# How I can use this pagination code as Multiple Table

Tags: php

I had found an example of paging entries using PHP and MySQL. I found out that it was designed for a single table only.

Now my problem is about how to page a "multiple queried table" (2 or more tables temporarily combined). My idea was to make a derived table from it, but it still failed.

Maybe I've done it wrong. What should be my proper query?

Comment: The link that this question relied upon has now died, so the question is now unfortunately off-topic. If you can make sure all of your questions are self-contained, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the SQL in pagination.php to reflect your joined tables.

Basically all that script does is check whether there are more rows after the rows already output, then show a link to increase the limit.

You can write your own just as easily:

Do a select count() of your joined tables to find the total number, then a while loop to find all rows, using a LIMIT $from, 10 to return only 10 rows.

If $from is still less than the total count, display your Next Page links...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UNION`, but yes you can join to query as shown here in my code:

```
$sqlCommand2 = "(SELECT id, product_name AS title, searchurl,img 
                   FROM products
                  WHERE product_name LIKE '%$searchquery%' 
                        OR details LIKE '%$searchquery%' '$limit'
                 ) UNION 
                 (SELECT id, product_name AS title, searchurl, img
                    FROM sellproducts
                   WHERE product_name LIKE '%$searchquery%' 
                         OR details LIKE '%$searchquery%' '$limit'
                 )";
```